# Update the data if the booking_endDate is lesser than current date

Tags: php, html

I am creating a booking management system. I got stuck in the booking status part. every booking id has their booking_startDate and booking_endDate, I want the system to update mysql table. if current date is one day more than end Date, then the booking status will change from in-room to complete.

I want to generate a query that can update the bookings whose booking end date is more than 1 day of the current date. How can I achieve this?

This is my database structure. [Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu9n9.png)

Comment: By writing an MySQL UPDATE query that uses the `NOW()` and `DATE_ADD()` functions in a suitable way. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, you are trying to complete the booking once end_date is less than current date so it don't matter if it's one day or more.

```
$format = 'Y-m-d'; //add your own format
$date  = date($format, strtotime("tomorrow"));
    
mysql_query("UPDATE booking SET booking_status = 'complete' WHERE date($date) = date(booking_endDate) AND booking_status != 'complete'");

//or you can use mysql for the same
mysql_query("UPDATE booking SET booking_status = 'complete' WHERE date(booking_endDate) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND booking_status != 'complete'");
```